# Airport filter is not accurate via FourSquare API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, foursquare

I'm developing an iOS App and I'm using FourSquare API - Venue Search to filter out the Airports alone. I have the category ID for the Airport which has been derived by API but in my results duplicates are showing and some Resturants are also showing. Please support me to get exactly the Airport lists.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:@"JYSZSD0V4CJVU3MRYWIKRKITXB3QWFRAPBLSPAWUJSTDRLVN" forKey:@"oauth_token"];
    [params setObject:@"airp" forKey:@"query"];
    [params setObject:@"11.0168,76.9558" forKey:@"ll"];
    [params setObject:@"20160607" forKey:@"v"];
    [params setObject:@"4bf58dd8d48988d1fd941735" forKey:@"categoryid"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search" parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *responseListPlaces = [NSDictionary new];
        responseListPlaces = responseObject[@"response"];
        NSArray *venusList = responseListPlaces[@"venues"];
        self->venuesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSDictionary *dic in venusList) {

             NSArray *catDetails =  dic[@"categories"];
            BOOL isVerifiedPlace =  dic[@"verified" ];

            NSString *catName = catDetails.firstObject[@"name"];

            if ([catName isEqualToString:@"Airport"]  ) {
                [self->venuesArray addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"name"]];
            }
        }


        NSLog(@"%@", self->venuesArray);
        [self->_venusListTbl reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

- `4bf58dd8d48988d1fd941735` is shopping mall.
- `4bf58dd8d48988d1ed931735` is Airport.

And you need to use `categoryId` param instead of `categoryid`.